# Remotely initialize RDP connection through SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop, openssh

I'm trying to find a way to remotely start RDP connection through ssh with cmd. It would work like this:

**Machine A** tells **Machine B** to connect with RDP to **Machine C**

I've tried logging into the **B** with ssh first and executing following command:

```
mstsc /v:ip_adress
```

but it seems that nothing happens on the **B**. What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to remotely tell with ssh to start RDP? All machines are running on Windows Server 2022.

Comment: Have you enabled the required role?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, RDP works when I try to connect from B to C when I'm on machine B but it just does not initiate through SSH. Moreover, not even RDP window pops up when I enter the command through SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution. I've installed psexec utility on machine **B** and used it through ssh with following format:

```
psexec -s -i session_id mstsc /v:rdp_ip
```

Where session_id is the id for logged user on **B**. I hope that will help someone in the future! :)